# Использование Container-а Symfony

Tags: symfony2

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TrainingBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeTrainingBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->container->get('service_container');
    }
```

AcmeTrainingBundle::getContainer()->get() - error "Call to a member function get() on null in"

делать return $this->container - тоже NULL

Comment: Зачем вам в бандле контейнер?

Comment: Контейнер мне нужен в кастомных классах

Comment: Но как его инжектить - хз

Comment: Его не надо инжектить, инжектить надо конкретные сервисы. В `services.yml` бандла пропишите новый сервис, в `arguments` напишите, все что, нужно, и эти сервисы придут в конструктор.

Comment: Отдельным комментарием: вы сейчас спрашиваете "а как мне заснунть контейнер в бандл?", в то время как вы пытаетесь засунуть что-то противоположно другое в не имеющий отношения к классу бандла класс, а мы должны гадать, что и как.

Comment: У меня сами сервисы использовать Container должны

Comment: Слабо представляю себе такую ситуацию, но еще раз: я не могу нормально ответить, пока сам вопрос не сформулирован толком.

Comment: В любом случае проблема в недостаточном прочтении документации. Спасибо большое, что помогли, пошел учить!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контейнер - это часть компонента [DependencyInjection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html). По-хорошему стоит прочитать про dependency inversion principle / inversion of control, что это и зачем вообще применяется, но основной смысл контейнера не в том, что он является хранилищем сервисов, а в том, что он эти сервисы умеет генерировать и разруливать зависимости между ними. Фактически, с помощью конфигурации описываются зависимости сервисов друг от друга, а в момент, когда код требует сервис, контейнер разруливает паутину зависимостей и досоздает все необходимые сервисы, которых на этот момент еще не хватает в контейнере. Поэтому инжектить сам контейнер не нужно - контейнер сам по себе является средством для инжекта других штук, и, по-хорошему, должен вызываться напрямую минимум раз.

Чтобы добавить свой сервис, его нужно описать в `Resources/config/services.yml` бандла или аналогичном конфигурационном файле. В теории, файл может называться как угодно, но вышеописанный сценарий воссоздается в ходе автоматического создания бандла, поэтому скорее всего он там и валяется.

Сервис описывается так:

```
my.cool.service: # имя сервиса, по которому он будет доступен в контейнере
  class: Name\Etki\MasterBundle\Service\StupidService
  arguments: # список аргументов, которые нужно передать в конструктор
    - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager # другой сервис - doctrine.orm.entity_manager является таким же идентификатором сервиса, как и my.cool.service
    - %database_host% # произвольный параметр из конфигурации
    - "HI THAR GUYSE" # произвольное значение
```

После такого описания при запросе `my.cool.service` в контейнере будет создан инстанс `Name\Etki\MasterBundle\Service\StupidService`, которому в конструктор придет EntityManager доктрины, хост базы данных и сверхтупая строка.

Comment: services:
app.training.controller:
      class: Acme\TrainingBundle\Controller\DefaultController
      arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]

и ошибка There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app.training.controller"

Хотя контроллер DefaultController имеет точно такое же пространство имен

Comment: В AppKernel-то бандл загружен?

Comment: Оказывается дело вообще в форматировании :о
Немного отступов сделал - все заработало...

Answer (score 1):

Это архитектурно неправильно. В *Bundle классах у вас еще происходит build Container-а. Вы можете повлиять на сборку своего бандла (добавить Extension-ы, CompilerPass-ы, etc.), но никак не получить уже готовый контейнер. В метод build, допустим, передается первым аргументом ContainerBuilder.